# Instagram API Can I request more than 1 user at once

Tags: api, instagram

This is the endpoint with example user

> https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/1574083/?access_token=209151370.f59def8.fc7e7d4789a947ff9364c1f15c578a99

with the 1574083 being the user id. Is there a way in these types of api's to request more than one user at once or do you need to make multiple requests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, not possible currently, only one user with a API call

Comment: Do you have any experience with Instagram API? Are you getting rate limited or have hit any type of cap?